# Custom styling for product attribute select boxes with jQuery

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, javascript, css

We have implemented the jQuery FancySelect script (http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/) to transform all the select boxes in our webshop. This works fine except for the select boxes on the product page to choose the options for product attributes.

The script changes the markup as follows:

**Before**

```
<select>
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
    <option value="optionId">Option</option>
    <option value="optionId">Option</option>
</select>
```

**After**

```
<select>
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
    <option value="optionId">Option</option>
    <option value="optionId">Option</option>
</select>
<div class="trigger">Choose an Option...</div>
<ul class="options">
    <li data-value="optionId">Option</li>
    <li data-value="optionId">Option</li>
</ul>
```

Although the custom styling is ok, we lose the standard Magento functionality to dynamically fill the additional select boxes with the available options when we have more then one product attribute.

This is probably due our new markup but we don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that there is no onchange event thrown. You can solve this e.g. with https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js

What you have to do is to fire onchange event, when this fancy select fires his onchange event.

Answer (score 0):

The updates between the select elements are triggered by using events that listen to change on the original select box, I'm guessing changing your JS replacement doesn't trigger the change even on the origin select element (I recently had a similar problem, when we placed Chosen on a store).

As a side note, you should probably check the country drop-down on the checkout to ensure this is in-fact working. Normally switching between a country that has Regions (such as France) and a country that doesn't (such as the UK) will result in a select element and text field switching visibility.  There's a good chance this doesn't work, or that the appearing select element isn't using your fancy widget. This of course all depends on what countries you allow.